# Appsync Subscription (with alias) not receiving updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Using GraphQL `alias` feature, no updates were received when mutation was invoked.

```
subscription OnPutItem($id: ID!) {
  item: onPutItem(id: $id) { // <---------- with alias
    id
    data
  }
}

mutation PutItem($data: String!) {
  item: PutItem(data: $data) { // <-------- with alias
    id
    data
  }
}
```

It works normally **without** the `item` alias.

Tested in Appsync console and app using `aws-amplify`.

[I didn't see any restrictions for `alias` not to be used in subscription](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Field-Alias).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. The fix for this has now been deployed, so you should see updates for mutations and subscriptions with aliases.

Comment: thanks! which aws-amplify release should I use with this fix? also I tried now using AppSync console, the alias is not shown in response (i.e. `data`)